# Integrate double tap/long press with swiping

Tags: java, android, swipe, double-click, long-press

I am trying to create a schedule app where if you swipe left or right, the schedule for the next and previous day will be displayed.

The swiping works, however I want to implement a feature where if you double tap or long press anywhere on the screen in the MainActivity, it opens up another activity.

My problem is that I cannot implement the double tap/long press along with the swiping. (I tried removing the onDown method of my OnSwipeTouchListener and adding an OnLongPressListener, but what ended up happening was that a swipe would also trigger the long press. Any help would be appreciated!!

main.xml for MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

OnSwipeTouchListener.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;  
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

protected final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            } 
            else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
                result = true;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }
}
```

Parts of MainActivity.java where I use OnSwipeTouchListener

```
            // Setup stuff
        LinearLayout layoutV = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        llV = layoutV;
        ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
        scroller = scroll;
        RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        rlayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                switchDays(-1);
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                switchDays(1);
            }

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        scroller.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                switchDays(-1);
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                switchDays(1);
            }
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        llV.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                switchDays(-1);
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                switchDays(1);
            }

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this?